# Como mudar todas as palavras selecionadas de uma só vez no VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ola gostaria de saber como mudar todas as palavras de uma só vez no visual studio code

obrigado

Comment: Se elas estão selecionadas, basta você digitar a nova. O VS Code possui suporte para multicursor.

Comment: A sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas se é mudar todas as palavras iguais no ficheiro aberto pode fazer selecionando a palavra e premindo `Ctrl` + `F2` e escrevendo o que quer por cima

Answer (score 6):

Há três formas:

**1 - Seleção de Linhas**

Você consegue colocar vários cursores pressionando <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> no local que deseja adicionar um novo curso, realizar uma ação, como adicionar letras ou remover, o VScode faz isso em todos os cursores ativos:

[image: VScode multi-cursores]

Você consegue colocar novos cursores pressionando <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> e <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>. Estes atalhos põem um novo cursor exatamente na mesma posição do primeiro uma linha a baixo e uma linha acima respectivamente.

**2 - Via Menu de Busca**

Abra o menu de buscas e expanda clicando na setinha a esquerda:

[image: expandindo menu de busca]

**3 - Via atalho para campo de substituição**

Pressione <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: Tem mais um jeito: selecionar uma palavra, clicar com o botão direito e escolher "change all occurrences".

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra opção é selecionar a palavra que quer, depois pressionar `alt+D`, cada vez que apertar `alt+D` ele vai selecionando essa palavra por todo seu projeto, ai depois é só digitar a nova que ele substitui em tudo.

No meu caso eu mudei o padrão do VSCode para ficar igual ao sublime text, troquei o ALT pelo CTRL. isso você faz nas configurações do VSCode

Comment: No macOS funciona com as teclas `cmd + D`, porém não é selecionado todas. A cada `cmd + D` vai adicionando a seleção a próxima palavra selecionada.

Answer (score 5):

Galera temos o CTRL+F2 (VsCode para Windows), basca colocar o cursor sobre a palavra (via seta ou mouse) e pressionar que todas serão alteradas. 
Usa-se o ESC pra sair

Answer (score -1):

pressione CTRL + SHIFT + H No VScode ele irá abrir no canto esquerdo uma espécie de toggle replace de massa para que você possa mudar várias palavras de uma vez só

Comment: Opa!
Melhora sua reposta, explica melhor para o pessoal poder entender.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui usando no win o cmd ctrl + D